# stuck on virtualenv / django

Tags: python, django, installation, virtualenv

I am stuck on the issues with virtualenv/django

My django had error in migrations and i messed up with few manipualtions:

- i updated django by pip
- i was adding PYTHONPATHs
- i removed and reinstalled env and my projects
- i removed all django manually from the Python38-32\lib\site-packages
  to reinstall

etc.
I thought i should reinstall virtualenv to start over again, but i can't

The error when I am trying to uninstall or install virtualenv below.
Any tips or solutions?

[image]

Comment: Oof. Can't you reinstall all of python and start over?

Comment: try using `pipenv` rather than `virtualenv`?

Comment: the same error appears if i am trying to uninstall python or install pipenv or start new django project